# RabbitMQ Sending objects

Tags: java, networking, rabbitmq, system-integration

Hello I'm new to RabbitMQ, I'm trying to send an object between 2 applications, but it's not working I then found out that I need to serialize and deserialize the objects but it's still not working. When I'm sending a String there is no problem, but with objects it's not working suddenly there is no connection between the application, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Here is the Sender.java :**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class App {

private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "12345";

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

    factory.setHost("somehost"); 
    factory.setUsername("guest"); 
    // factory.setPassword( "password" ); 
    //factory.setPort( 12345 ); 

    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);

    Car car = new Car(4, 4, "Mercedes");

    byte[] data = SerializationUtils.serialize(car);

    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, data);
    System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + data + "'");

    channel.close();
    connection.close();
   }
}
```

**Here is Receiver.java :**

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Recipient {

     private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "12345";

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("Somehost");
    factory.setUsername("guest"); 
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
    Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {

        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                throws IOException {

            String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
            //byte [] data = new byte[];

            Object object =    SerializationUtils.deserialize(message.getBytes());

            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + object + "'");
         }
      };
    channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
     }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean that there isn't connection between the applications? How are you checking it? Are you looking at the management screen? If you aren't checking it, I'd suggest adding a System.out.println right at the top of the handleDelivery method to see if it reaches in there at all

Comment: anyone that can help?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
            throws IOException {
        //byte [] data = new byte[];

        Object object =    SerializationUtils.deserialize(body);

        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + object + "'");
     }
  };
```

Just deserialize directly from the `body` variable